# Request body is empty after POST request on nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, request, hapi.js, nock

I am trying to the below post request from my test.js but alas I am trying since 2 hrs waiting for a hurry moment that my test gets successful but it ain't.

Please find the below code with nock.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  var payload = {
    channel: 'Cricket',
    codes: 'c--HOjyWVww:APA'
  };
  scope = nock('http://localhost:3000')
    .post('/channel/subscribe', payload)
    .reply(200, { status: 200 });
});
request.post('http://localhost:3000/channel/subscribe', function(err, body) {
  console.log(err, null);
});

it('Subscribing to channel', function(done) {
      request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/channel/subscribe',
        headers: {
          'accept': 'application/json',
          'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          channel: "Cricket",
          codes: "c--HOjyWVww:APA"
        })
      }, function(err, response) {
        console.log(request.payload);
        console.log("+response status code:", response.statusCode);
        console.log(response.failureCount);
        if (err) {
          throw err; // => Error: Nock: No match for request POST http://foobar.com/ {"foo":"biz"}
        }
        done();
      })
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you set bodyParser in your application?
like:

```
app.use(bParser.json());
```

In your own case it should be:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Hi the code is not in express js, its with nodejs code